# Let a PHP script repeatedly redirect to itself, ignoring browser timeout

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, timeout

My father wants to build a newsletter dispatch system which provides customized fields as part of a tailor-made system. The users can use some special variables in the text to insert the name of the recipient (among other things).

The last HTML form asking for all the data in the email will insert the data as well as the set of recipients into the database. Then the user is redirected to the worker script.

In the worker script (let's call it `worker.php`) he roughly has the following:

```
# Get current job from the database.
# Pop off the first recipient in the list.
# Retrieve additional data about that recipient from the database.
# Generate and send email.
# Store truncated list of recipients in database.

if (work_left) {
    header('Location: worker.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: done.php');
}
```

The worker only does a single work-item in order to dodge the PHP time limit. The system is to be deployed on a shared hoster which might have the most arcane `php.ini` settings.

It works, the work-items are handled and the number of recipients in the database shrinks. The unforeseen problem now is that the browser eventually runs into a timeout, canceling the connection. The PHP script is then canceled and no more work is done. The process is easily restarted by pointing the browser back to `worker.php`, but this is something that the end-user should not have to do.

A quick search on this site gave me the [`ignore_user_abort`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function which looks promising in order to dodge the browser timeout. I fear that this does not solve the problem in this situation: The browser will close the connection at some point. The currently running PHP script will finish running and then tell the browser to reload `worker.php`. The browser is not listening any more, the progress also stops. This is an improvement as it does not stop mid-transaction, but not a solution.

Another idea that we had was replacing the redirect with one to `worker2.php`. That PHP file just contains a redirect back to `worker.php`. This might be sufficient progress to the browser that it will continue to load and not bump into the timeout (hopefully the timeout is per URL at least?).

If that would not work either, then a HTML redirect with `<meta>` might be another option. The `worker.php` would then actually finish to load and the browser would be able to finish the request. The `<meta>` would then redirect to `worker.php` again to do the next work-item. This last one has the disadvantage that it still depends on the browser to be open.

In the very best case he is looking for a solution which would run through, once it is started. The browser could timeout, the user could close the window and the script would still run through and send all the emails. Is it possible to generate a worker such that it is immune to PHP execution time limit and browser timeouts?

Comment: If you want it to keep running even after a browser closes, you need to kick off a background process with http://php.net/exec. Kick off a separate PHP script in the background, and _that_ background script can remove the timeout completely and run as long as it needs to.

Comment: exec another php process in the background, or `fork()` the current process. either will become independent of the webserver and not be subject to anything the user does on their end.

Comment: @jszobody: I assume that the separate PHP process should be generated with `exec('/usr/bin/php path/to/worker.php');`? Most likely this is not possible on shared hosters (without extra payment), so we will need to check that. If one does `exec`, it does not get killed when the PHP script gets killed by the timeout, does it?

Comment: @MartinUeding read up on how to execute a php script as a background process. It's beyond the scope of this comment section. You can ensure that it keeps running after the parent script is killed. And it is not subject to the php.ini timeout settings.

Comment: @MartinUeding: Were you able to use `exec` on the shared hoster? The comments in the documentation seem promising. Additionally, did changing the order of emails in the `multipart/alternate` mail fix your father's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of relying on fancy background script on shared hosting just use crontab (even if Your hosting provider doesn't give You one You can use some services which will allow You simulate cron), which will fire script once per minute (?). Script will check if there is some work in queue table, pick some (as much as your server will allow You to process) and marking processed tasks as completed (or removing them from table). You can then provide some endpoint which can be accessed by sender to see his progress (count all tasks for user and those marked as completed).
I don't think that You are able to use RabbitMQ + supervisord or something similar on shard, but I don't think that using background php script is good idea :)